# How to make headless Raspberry Pi automatically perform a command over ssh?

Tags: pi-4, ssh

I have a headless Raspberry Pi accessed from my Mac over WiFi. However, whenever I lose the connection, it stops doing whatever I'm having it do; is there a way to make the Pi do a command on its own, post-SSH, for an indefinite period of time?

Comment: the question should be `how to detect connection drop?`

Answer (score 2):

This is not Pi specific - it is a general Linux question - better asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions.

You can start a process in the background or use `tmux`
See
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/132983/8697 for examples

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the program you have started under `ssh` becomes "orphaned" when the `ssh` session eventually dies, and the "orphaned" program is most likely terminated.

Fortunately, there are several options available to prevent the program you started from being terminated. If your SSH connections are subject to random and untimely dropouts, I think a *"terminal multiplexer"* may be your best choice. The two most common are `screen` and `tmux`. `screen` is included with macOS (at least with my versions), but it's an older version. You can get a newer version of `screen`, or `tmux` via [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) or Homebrew. Whatever you decide to use, read the manual: e.g. `man screen`. There are good Q&As on [Unix&LinuxSE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/479/keep-processes-running-after-ssh-session-disconnects), and [AskUbuntuSE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8653/how-to-keep-processes-running-after-ending-ssh-session) that cover your question very well.

Another option is to use is `nohup` - also included on macOS. It's an "old school" option, but can work well ***if your program doesn't require any input from the terminal***. There's a ton of information available for the cost of an Internet search; here's a good [Q&A from Unix&LinuxSE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/difference-between-nohup-disown-and), and a [brief tutorial](https://linuxhint.com/nohup_command_linux/).